# lvalue required as increment operand using pointers and struct

Tags: c, loops, pointers, for-loop

May I know whats wrong?

```
for ( ; *line[0]; ++line[0], ++p->title) p->title = tolower(*line[0]);
```

p is a struct and title is a char pointer, line is a string/char pointer

```
typedef struct p{
    char *title;
} p;
```

I'm trying to convert the string to all lower case.

Comment: You should post the declaration of the `struct` for `p`. What's `p->surname`?

Comment: @TedHopp I have posted the declaration for the `struct` and `p->surname` is a typo

Comment: Please post the exact error message from the compiler.

Comment: @JohnBode `lvalue required as increment operand for for ( ; *line[0]; ++line[0], ++p->title) p->title = tolower(*line[0]);`

Answer (score 2):

You are using p as a pointer to a struct. If you need title you should use the period operator like this:

```
p.title
```

Comment: Except in the little bit of code that's been posted, `p` isn't even a variable; it's a typedef name.

Comment: p is a variable of struct p

Comment: @jon: Not in the code you posted.  In the snippet you provided, you created `p` as a typedef name (synonym) for the type `struct p`.